# I have 20gb of extra space and i cant find windows.old

Tags: windows

There is this extra 20gb of space in my Temporary Files that I can't seem to find. I have searched up on this issue and a lot of people says its the windows.old file but i can't seem to find that either [20+ gb of extra space here](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

[cant find windows.old when i try other methods as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhlRi.png)

Comment: Your first image isn’t accessible

Comment: x#.. was there some reason why you did not follow up?

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Explorer, and then View, Right Side, Options.

Change Folder and Search Options. View tab.

Select View Hidden Files and Folders.

Close out, restart (not really needed, just to be sure). Now you can see Windows.old at the bottom of C:  Root.

Run Disk Cleanup (Admin Tools) and select Clean up System files. Proceed until done. There will be a confirmation prompt to delete Windows.old. Say Yes if your system is working well.

This all works for me.